# Open XML File in same workbook as Macro

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am writing a macro which will import some XML data and then do some clever things with it. The following code opens the XML but as a new workbook - can anyone advise how to open it into the current workbook?

```
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
```

Cheers

Edit - Here is some code which does the job

```
Sub OpenXML()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sDelimiter As String
Dim newSheet As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sDelimiter = ","

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(FileFilter:="XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", _
MultiSelect:=True, Title:="XML File to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

For x = 1 To UBound(FilesToOpen)

    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
     'wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
     ' here you just want to create a new sheet and paste it to that sheet
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    With newSheet
        .Name = "Original_XML"
        .PasteSpecial
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wkbTemp.Close
Next x
End Sub()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the xml to the workbook this way without opening it:

```
ThisWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
    s_FilePath, ImportMap:=Nothing, _
    Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

In your code it would look like this:

```
Sub OpenXML()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer

Dim sDelimiter As String
Dim newSheet As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sDelimiter = ","

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(FileFilter:="XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", _
MultiSelect:=True, Title:="XML File to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

With ActiveWorkbook
    For x = 1 To UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set newSheet = .Sheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "Original_XML_" & x
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .XmlImport URL:= _
            FilesToOpen(x), ImportMap:=Nothing, _
            Overwrite:=True, Destination:=newSheet.Range("A1")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next x
End With

ExitHandler:
ErrHandler:
End Sub
```